# How can I remove all trailing dashes from a string?

Tags: python

Example:

```
string1 = 'title--'
string2 = 'title-'
string3 = 'this-is-a-title----'

>> print doSomething(string1)
>> title

>> print doSomething(string2)
>> title

>> print doSomething(string3)
>> this-is-a-title
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
string1.rstrip("-")
# "title"
string2.rstrip("-")
# "title"
string3.rstrip("-")
# "title-is-a-title"
```